# Postgres full text search to_tsvector not using index

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

The query matches the index, why is doing Seq Scan on movies? It should be using Bitmap Heap Scan.

psql (PostgreSQL) 15.4 (Homebrew)

Index:

```
​CREATE​ ​INDEX​ movies_title_searchable ​ON​ movies​ ​USING​ gin(to_tsvector(​'english'​, title));
```

Query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT title
FROM movies
WHERE to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'night & day') LIMIT 1;
```

```
->  Seq Scan on movies  (cost=0.00..2.31 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, title) @@ '''night'' & ''day'''::tsquery)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3
```

Comment: It's an almost empty table, using an index would make it slower. You could turn enable_seqscan OFF: `SET enable_seqscan TO off;`

Comment: Correct, this is a brand new table, I'm just trying to understand why the index is not being picked up.

Comment: Using the index would make the query slower: first read the index and second, read the table. Using a sequential read on just the (empty) table, is faster. 2 blocks of 8kB vs 1 block of 8kB. Never test with empty tables for performance, makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, postgres won't use the index due the table size (too small).

> The query planner may determine a direct read from the heap is preferable to the cost of an index scan, even if there are index hits available. It’s most common for Postgres to choose this path if the index scan itself would return a significant portion of data in the table. As a result, Postgres frequently skips over indexes for small tables.

Comment: If you have five books on a shelf by your bed, would you consult a catalog if you wanted to select one of them?

Comment: Size is not the only variable in here, it's also the number of potential records you're looking for compared to the total number of records. Any database would make a big mistake to use an index, just because there is an index. Imagine a table with 1 billion records and numerical primary key, id, with values between 1 and 1 billion. And now you start a query `SELECT * FROM t WHERE id between 1 and 1000000000;` It would be the worst thing possible to use the index on the PK. When you  need just a (relative) small sub set `WHERE id between 900 and 1000;` it would make sense to use the index.